# SQL: Return left join as object

Tags: sql, postgresql

Fairly new to SQL so I'm very sorry if this is not possible at all.

I'm essentially using SQL queries to get data from my database and then passing them to a Graphql API. This has worked great up until now as my queries were fairly simple:

```
SELECT * from a_single_table
```

I've now gotten to the point where with those simple requests, I would like to `JOIN` other data from a different table, for example the user associated with the specific resource:

```
 id | username  
----+------------
  1 | User1
  2 | User2
  3 | User3
```

I can easily join the two by doing something like (pseudo-query warning):

```
SELECT *, u.username, u.id FROM a_single_table AS s LEFT JOIN users_table AS u ON (s.authorId = u.id)
```

Unfortunately if I do this the structure of the data I get back is a flat table, so it'll look something like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: "The title of the resource selected",
  username: "User1"
  userId: 1
}
```

It would be much better for Graphql's syntax if it was return like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: "The title of the resource selected",
  user: {
    userId: 1,
    username: "User1"
  }
}
```

Is this at all possible? Currently using Postgresql if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if your question is about Postgres structs or JSON formatting.  But Postgres supports structures which are equivalent to a row in a table.  So, you can do:

```
SELECT s.*, u
FROM a_single_table s LEFT JOIN
     users_table u
     ON s.authorId = u.id;
```

It is also possible to construct a JSON object for each row:

```
SELECT json_buil_object('id', s.id, 'title', s.title, 'user', u)
FROM a_single_table s LEFT JOIN
     users_table u
     ON s.authorId = u.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this

```
SELECT firsttable.*, to_json("secondtable") AS keyyouwant
FROM a_single_table s LEFT JOIN
     users_table u
     ON s.authorId = u.id;
```